# Was there ever an incident of collision between SRBs after SRB jettison, during launch of the Space Shuttle?

Tags: launch, space-shuttle, srb

Did the Space Shuttle solid rocket boosters (SRBs) ever collide with each other after separation from the Shuttle stack?

To clarify, I'm not asking if an SRB ever collided with the Shuttle itself or the external tank.  I'm asking if the SRBs ever collided with each other while in free fall after separation.

Comment: Short answer, no.  The booster sep rockets pushed them off to the sides.  This is likely a duplicate question.  And yes, it never happened.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.  I'm not asking if an SRB ever collided with the shuttle or external tank.

I'm more curious if during free fall the two ever bumped into each other.  I realize that they jettison apart and should not collide.

Comment: This looks to me too like a different question than [whether the SRBs could hit the Shuttle stack](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/12381/415). I edited further to emphasize the difference. Michael Gantz, if you feel my edit changed your intent, feel free to roll back the edit or to [edit] further!

Comment: Michael Kjörling, I think the current question conveys my intent perfectly.

Comment: It never happened, but good luck finding a reference that says that.