# Did the shuttle SRBs have separation motors?

Tags: space-shuttle, sls, srb

Looking at a NASA fact sheet about the SLS SRBs and I noticed it has at the bottom around the nozzle, separation motors.

[image: SLS SRB diagram from NASA fact sheet]

Watching shuttle launches It looks to me like the SRBs continue to fire normally but there's a short change in the exhaust around separation. Did the shuttle's SRBs have something similar? If they did, I would like to know more detail on how they work. Like what's their fuel, how long did they burn?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: [Is it possible for the SRBs to hit the shuttle after separation?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12382/195)

Comment: Related: [What are these circular spots on these Ariane V SRB nozzles?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37961/195)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, each shuttle SRB had a cluster of Booster Separation Motors (BSMs) at the top and bottom of the booster.  Four solid motors in each cluster fired for just more than a second producing 22,000 lbf each.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booster_separation_motor

The BSMs were fired by commands sent from the Orbiter onboard computers to the Master Events Controller which charged up and fired the pyrotechnic ignitors on the motors and explosive separation bolts.

[image]

[image]

Information and diagrams from the [1982 Press Manual](https://ia802904.us.archive.org/24/items/PressInformationSpaceShuttleTransportationSystemMarch1982/Press_Information_Space_Shuttle_Transportation_System_March_1982.pdf), annotations mine.

This SRB-mounted video camera shows a good view of the plumes from the forward BSMs firing.

Personal photos of the BSMs from the STS-124 SRBs on the launch pad.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The link you have for wikipedia has an exlempary video +1. Ive wondered about this but didn't know the monicker. Booster separation motor is good to know diction wise.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn check out the video from the SRB cam!

Comment: Thanks! I figured they probably had something, but for some reason for the longest time I thought they just reduced the thrust at the end then separated and just had those small thrusters on top.